# Custom Cells in TableView: Failed to obtain a cell from its Data Source

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using the below code to use two different custom table cells in my table view. Everything looks right, however when I run the app, I get the following error:

> Failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource 
>   FullMessageViewController: 0x103d61c90

Any idea why this might be?

**FullMessageViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


   static NSString *ChatTableIdentifier = @"ChatTableViewCell";
   static NSString *ChatTableIdentifier2 = @"SwapDetailTableViewCell";


    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName: ChatTableIdentifier bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier: ChatTableIdentifier];

    UINib *nib2 = [UINib nibWithNibName: ChatTableIdentifier2 bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib2 forCellReuseIdentifier: ChatTableIdentifier2];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   static NSString *ChatTableIdentifier = @"ChatTableViewCell";
   static NSString *ChatTableIdentifier2 = @"SwapDetailTableViewCell";


    NSDictionary *data = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


   if (![data objectForKey:@"field_swaptime"]) {

     NSLog(@"THIS IS DATA %@", data);



       ChatTableViewCell *cell = (ChatTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChatTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


       NSString *userName = [data objectForKey:@"name"];
       [cell.sendingUser setText:userName];

       NSString *messageBody = [data objectForKey:@"body"];
       [cell.messageDisplayed setText:messageBody];

       NSString *timeReceived = [data objectForKey:@"published at"];
       NSLog(@"Message Received at %@", timeReceived);
       [cell.timeStamp setText:timeReceived];


     return cell;

              }

    else {


        SwapDetailTableViewCell *cell = (SwapDetailTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChatTableIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];



        NSString *Time = [data objectForKey:@"field_swaptime"];
        NSLog(@"This is time %@", Time);
        [cell.startTime setText:Time];

        NSString *TimeEnd = [data objectForKey:@"field_endswaptime"];
        [cell.endTime setText:TimeEnd];

        return cell;

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are registering a nib for your cell types, you need to replace the use of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`.

Example. Change:

```
ChatTableViewCell *cell = (ChatTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChatTableIdentifier];
```

to:

```
ChatTableViewCell *cell = (ChatTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChatTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

And you have some typos in `viewDidLoad`. Update it as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    static NSString *ChatTableIdentifier = @"ChatTableViewCell";
    static NSString *ChatTableIdentifier2 = @"SwapDetailTableViewCell";

    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName: ChatTableIdentifier bundle:nil];  
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier: ChatTableIdentifier];

    UINib *nib2 = [UINib nibWithNibName: ChatTableIdentifier2 bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib2 forCellReuseIdentifier: ChatTableIdentifier2];
}
```

Comment: I change the line as you suggest, and then I get this error (which seems strange, because I did register the nib?): 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier ChatTableViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: Make sure you are using the constants and not string literals. In other words, use `ChatTableIdentifier`, not `@"ChatTableIdentifier"`.

Comment: Ok, this fixes the crash! However all of the cells in my table appear to be using ChatTableViewCell, and there's no sign of SwapDetailTableViewCell? (e.g. if field_swaptime contains data, SwapDetailTableViewCell should be used?)

Comment: Make sure you don't have a typo in `viewDidLoad` where you register the nib and cell (use your `ChatTableIdentifier2` identifier, not `ChatTableIdentifier`). And make sure you use the correct identifier in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Double checked - see my edited code above! Let me know if you see anything that looks nuts (a second set of eyes might help - I feel like I'm taking crazy pills at this point lol). O_O As far as I know, the above edits should be working.

Comment: Use the debugger. Step through the code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Is it that the `if` statement is always true and you get only `ChatTableViewCell` or is it that some rows go to the `else` part but you still somehow getting the wrong cell type?

Comment: Did you accidentally set the same cell subclass in both of your nib files?

Comment: I checked the debugger, and in self.messages, the console shows:  swaptime = "<null>"; - So I know beyond a shadow of a doubt there isn't anything in that field in the specified cell. If that is true (swaptime = "<null>"), that cell appear as SwapDetailTableViewCell, correct?

Comment: It's hard to say based on what you are saying. You're are now talking about a completely separate issue from the one asked in this question. I suggest you close this question by accepting one of the answer as you see fit. Then post a new question specific to this new issue related to the `if` statement and the data in `self.messages`. Be sure you provide log output from showing the value of `self.messages` and any other relevant details so people can help you find the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check this line on viewDidLoad

```
[self.tableView registerNib:nib2 forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ChatTableIdentifier2"];
```

You're registering a nib with the identifier `ChatTableIdentifier2` but you don't actually use that identifier in cellForRowAtIndexPath, you use `SwapDetailTableViewCell`.

Changing that line to

```
[self.tableView registerNib:nib2 forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SwapDetailTableViewCell"];
```

should work

Comment: SwapDetailTableViewCell *cell = (SwapDetailTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChatTableIdentifier2]; -I do use ChatTableIdentifier2?? On this line?

Comment: Yes, but that's the variable name, the actual value is "SwapDetailTableViewCell".

Comment: If that's the case, then should the first registered nib be "ChatTableViewCell" instead of "ChatTableIdentifier"?

Comment: Indeed it should! Missed that one.